# Sending email in MVC6?

Tags: email, asp.net-core-mvc, mailkit

I have tried referencing system.net.mail in various frameworks:

```
framework: "net451"
dependency: "System.Net.Mail": "1.0.0-rc2-00001"
error: does not support framework

framework: "net46"
dependency: "System.Net.Mail": "1.0.0-rc2-00001"
error: does not support framework

framework: "dotnet5.4"
System.Net.Mail not available

framework: "dnx46"
System.Net.Mail not available
```

I have also tried using email package MailKit 1.2.21, installed from NuGet.

```
"net46": {
        "dependencies": {
            "MailKit": "1.2.21"
        }
```

If I reference MailKit class, error: "The type of namespace cannot be found".

How do I send email in MVC 6?

Answer (score 1):

I have given up with the 3rd party libraryies.  I created an Azure storage table, and the websites save their emails to this table.  I have a Raspberry Pi in the server room which looks for new emails on the Azure table every 1 minute, pulls them off the table and sends them.  There is a library for accessing Azure storage using Linux Python.

Also set up a 3G dongle on the PI and now can send SMS texts from my MVC6 websites as well!

This is far away from the solution I was looking for, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

MailKit does not currently have an assembly specific to `net46`, but there's no reason you couldn't use the `net45` MailKit assembly.

Apparently nuget does not figure this out automatically for you and just reference the `net45` assembly, so you'll have to do it manually.

I'll try to make the next MimeKit and MailKit release include `net46` assemblies in the nuget package (which will probably just be `net45` assemblies in the `net46` directory in the nuget), but I'm holding off on making a new release until Microsoft releases dotnet 1.0 rc2.

I've been expecting this release every day for about a month now :(